# Correctness of algorithm for generating a random list of numbers from 1 to n

Tags: algorithm, random

Given a function `Random(x, y)` which returns a random number between `x` and `y` (inclusive). Design an algorithm to print a list of unique_random_numbers from `1` to `n`.
There must be `n` numbers in the list and every number must appear only once.

e.g.

```
PrintRandomList(1, 5) can print -> 2, 5, 1, 4, 3    
PrintRandomList(1, 6) can print -> 4, 1, 6, 3, 2, 5
```

I've been able to come-up with an algorithm but couldn't prove that it will generate a truly random list (Assume that `Random(x, y)` will generate true random numbers).

```
void PrintRandomList(int a, int b) {
    if(a<=b) {
        int pivot = Random(a, b);
        printf("%d ", pivot);
        PrintRandomList(a, pivot-1);
        PrintRandomList(pivot+1, b);    
    }
}
```

My question: **Is the algorithm correct?** If yes then, **can we prove the correctness of the algorithm?**

If this algorithm is correct than we can also use it to shuffle an array instead of using Knuth Shuffling Algorithm.

Comment: Try to run your algorithm over the same input a number of times.

Comment: @devull: that "proves" nothing...

Comment: It is easy to see that it cannot be correct. It never generates a sequence like 2, 3, 1

Comment: It's correct 100%. you want a mathmatical proof. I dont' have it. I am bad in math expression. and there is alot of ways to suffle an array.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it seems obvious to me that it won't generate a random list. It will generate a list with a random first element, then all the elements below that, then all the elements above that. Within the two "below" and "above" sections, the same pattern will apply, but given PrintRandomList(1,3) this can never generate 2,3,1.

Comment: @Henry In this algorithm I first print the pivot than go in left-half than go in right-half. If I randomly decide the half (left or right) to go first then will the algorithm be correct?

Comment: it will be a shuffled numbers without repetition. but the all possible shuffling permutations don't have the same chance to appear.

Comment: @Henry: Just because it cannot generate each possible sequence doesn't mean it's not correct. Actually one could argue that always returning 1,2,3,4,5,6 is 'correct', too, just the probability between the different possible sequences is not really well distributed ;-)

Comment: You will always generate a true random number followed by a lower number followed by a higher number... which is not random

Comment: @Sebastian the OP mentions "couldn't prove that it will generate a truly random list", this implies that all possible sequences can be generated.

Comment: I have a great idea. if you want all the permutations to have same chance to appear. go and generate a random number 0 or 1 to decide which of the two statements to run first. PrintRandomList(a, pivot-1); or PrintRandomList(pivot+1, b);  :)

Comment: @Henry it will generate if he add my suggestion. check it.

Comment: @hasan there are other counter examples then, one is 3, 2, 4, 1

Comment: A simple way to do this: Generate numbers 1 to n and [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to the root question of proving if this algorithm works is that you must prove that *every* outcome is *equally* possible. As other have pointed out, that's not the case here.

If you can find any sequence that is unreachable or even less likely to be reached then you know the algorithm is not "fair". The converse of this argument proves that it is.

Comment: In this algorithm I first print the pivot than go in left-half than go in right-half. If I randomly decide the half (left or right) to go first then will the algorithm be correct?

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan see my comment in the above question, no; because there is a predictable pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your algo isn't correct, most of the times the numbers from 1 to n/2 will be in the first half of the returned list (imagine that pivot returns roughly n/2). (not easy to prove that it is not correct either ^^)

You need to think a bit more, but if you ask we can give tips